# How to install OS in virt-manager in kali linux v2.0

Tags: kali-linux, virtual-machine, virt-manager

I have installed Kali Linux in Laptop. Now I have installed `virt-manager` in Kali. But while installing "fedora 22" in virtual machine it crashes.

Below are some command output:

```
service libvirtd status

Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-05-02 20:14:06 IST; 57min ago
root@kali:~# virsh list --all
Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
2     fedora22                       running
```

**problem is here:**

```
root@kali:~# virt-viewer fedora22
*** Error in `virt-viewer': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000afb9c0 ***
Aborted
```

This is using `virt-manager` version 1.3.2, `libvirtd` (`libvirt`) version 1.3.3, `virt-viewer` version 3.1. All these seem to be recent releases.

Answer (score 1):

[Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Error+in+%60virt-viewer%27:+free%28%29:+invalid+pointer) says this is a [known bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93498).

The recommended fix from that bug seems to be to use a (more) recent version of `libvirt` and `virt-viewer`, but there's no evidence that this will help.

Comment: i m using latest version.

Comment: @Tiger that's a relative term. What are the exact versions of these two tools that you're using?

Comment: virt-manager 1.3.2 version,libvirtd (libvirt) 1.3.3 version, virt-viewer version 3.1

Comment: @Tiger that bug still looks relevant. You can add your information to the bug report and then it'll likely get reopened and investigated.